# Get mysql column values to row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table for bookings

```
Bookingid  Customer

  1         Steve
  2         John
```

and another table for passengers

```
Bookingid  Passenger

  1        Steve
  1        Gary
  1        Tom
  2        John
  2        Chris
  2        Thomas
```

What is the best query to get bookingid from the first table and passengers from the second table, in a single row ?

```
Bookingid  Passenger1 Passenger2 Passenger3
  1         Steve       Gary      Tom
  2         John        Chris     Thomas
```

Comment: Are the number of `PassengerN` fixed or variable ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos number of Passengers are variable

Comment: So, look at my given answer. You need a PIVOT TABLE. Which is, in my opinion, painfull to do directly over mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t do this without a [PIVOT TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) Wich in most cases has fixed numbers of columns to rows.

This one has a procedure to do it automatticaly http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523

But you have a function on MySql wich will give you something to work with. You will not see the `Passenger1..PassengerN` you will see a result like this:

```
1 Steve, Gary, Tom
2 John, Chris, Thomas
```

If that is good enough to you this is your query:

```
select passengers.Bookingid, group_concat(bookings.Customer)
  from bookings inner join passengers on ( bookings.Bookingid = passengers.Bookingid )
group by passengers.Bookingid
```